# How do I get a form to submit the first time I hit enter in react?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input

I feel like there is an easy fix for this but I am not finding it. After I first open the page, type a number in the input and hit submit I get an empty array in the console and no number is displayed. When I hit enter again it works. How do I get the number to display the first time?

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';

const ShowDays = () =>{
const [totalMiles, setTotalMiles] = useState([])
const [miles, setMiles] = useState([])
const [total, setTotal] = useState([])

const handleChange = (e) =>{
  setMiles(e.target.value)

}

const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();

  setTotalMiles([...totalMiles].concat(Number(miles)
  
  ))

  if (totalMiles !== []){
   let result = totalMiles.reduce((total, n) =>{
      return total += n
    })
    setTotal(result)

  }
  

}

return (
  <div>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input type='text' placeholder='enter miles' onChange={handleChange} value={miles}/>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  <p>{`Total Milage: ${total} `}</p>
  </div>
)
    
}

export default ShowDays;
```

I've tried many different things but nothing seems to work

Comment: I believe the `concat` method needs to take an array. An easier way might be `setTotalMiles([...totalMiles, Number(miles)])`

Comment: Thank you Nick for the tip. For some reason I still get the same result. On the first submit I get Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value. I think react is trying to sum the array before the state is set. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: I actually wouldn't recommend storing `total` as its own state, it's purely derived. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Okay, added my answer and a link to a working example

Answer (score -1):

The [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method concatenates two *arrays*, but you're passing a number. Instead, consider setting the total miles this way:

```js
setTotalMiles([...totalMiles, Number(miles)]);
```

Also, I recommend not storing `total` as its own state since it's completely derived from existing state. You can just calculate it in the function body:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const ShowDays = () => {
  const [totalMiles, setTotalMiles] = useState([]);
  const [miles, setMiles] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setMiles(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTotalMiles([...totalMiles, Number(miles)]);
  };

  const total = totalMiles.reduce((total, n) => total + n, 0);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="enter miles"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={miles}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <p>{`Total Milage: ${total} `}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShowDays;
```

Here is a [working codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-dubinsky-jwil1p?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Don’t use `total` in the function scope like this, it gets processed every time the component render. You should use a callback or memo hook if going this route.

Comment: @Andy the cost of rerunning that total calculation is likely pretty negligible. If he needs to memoize its invocation eventually that's fine, but generally the React core team recommends against premature optimization.

Comment: Aside from inside the function scope, how exactly would you call it?

Comment: That’s not premature optimization. Premature optimization cuts deeper than just a usecallback hook, it involves builds and much more. However in this case it a data process that *could cost nothing or a lot. If you are using an array with a reducer what’s the issue or placing in a hook? It won’t hurt now and possibly prevent an issue when it’s demanded performance later.

Comment: I can see that I am not going to convince you that memoizing a reduce calculation in a toy mileage calculator before it's a known issue is premature optimization. That's okay--it seems like my answer unblocked OP, which is what I was going for.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is important to understand why this is happening.

The setState hook is asynchronous. So by the time you trying to check the value in the if statement. The state setter hasn’t yet finished. So the value doesn’t yet exit in current state which has been queued to be available in the next life cycle.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();

  setTotalMiles(prevState => ([…prevState, Number(miles)])
  
  ))

  if (totalMiles.length){
   let result = totalMiles.reduce((total, n) =>{
      return total += n
    })
    setTotal(result)
  }
  
}
```

See docs.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate